# Finding ESR of LCR circuit?

Tags: resistance, esr, lcr, resonant

I have an LCR circuit, and I am trying to find the ESR of a capacitor.
I bought a [820uH inductor](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bourns/SRR1280A-821K?qs=jtImr9hqsuEBw7koXPUdUg%3D%3D) , and an ultra-low [1000pF capacitor](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Kyocera-AVX/12101U102JAT2A?qs=tl6yqnxyPsEIz9T58e4c0g%3D%3D), and a 46.6ohm 1% tolerance  resistor.

Below is my circuit with measured data on the chart.
The Vin is 1.5Vpeak sine wave with frequency of around 180kHz; I am using a signal generator and the output of the signal generator goes to the voltage follower. The output of the voltage follower connects to the Inductor, Capacitor and Resistor in series. I have made sure that the Vin and Vout are in-phase; therefore at resonant (Signal shown below). I have Rref of 46.6ohm with increasing R1 value.

**Result:** Using voltage divider @ resonant frequency, I was able to get Resr + RL of around 17ohm.
Why is my Resr + RL = 17ohm when the capacitor ESR is milliohm and the inductor max resistance is 1.5ohm; I should be getting close of 1.5ohm for Resr +RL but I am getting around 17ohm.

Please help out what I am missing.

[image]

In-phase signal

[image]

Capacitor ESR datasheet:

[image]

Inductor max DC resistance of 1.5ohm.

[image]

Comment: The datasheet ESR is for the parasitics - i.e. resistance other than due to the capacitive reactance. The simulation is measuring the ESR due to reactance.

Comment: What is Vin ? a signal generator (50 ohm?)  Why does it change?. Are you attempting to validate DCR of L and ESR of NPO cap?  If yes, then this is the wrong bridge method

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Yes, I am trying to validate the ESR of the capacitor, and DCR of L. The voltage source or Vin is the output of a voltage follower. The input to the voltage follower is a signal generator. The output of the voltage follower connects to the LCR circuit. The output of the voltage follower is close to 3Vp-p. I don't think the Vin changes much. 820uH, and 1000pF are at resonance at180kHz. When they are resonant, the real resistance remains (reactance goes away). The will help me find the Resr + RL. What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the exact schematic of your test results. Voltage follower?? does that mean source impedance < 1 mohm, or  Rb/hFE for output impedance.  Your assumptions for KVL should be that Vin never changes. If it does, then your results are in error.   Next you want to use a load close to the unknown resistance or calibrate with 0 mOhms low voltage to validate your assumptions.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Since the signal generator has 50ohm source impedance, I used voltage follower. The output of the voltage follower connects to the LCR.  If I connect the signal generator directly to the LCR, the input signal distorts; therefore, voltage follower is must. The source impedance is low (one of the properties of opamp).

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Lets say that the Vinput did changes slightly (2.92V as shown in the signal image), the Vout will correspond as well. The ESR reading as I increase the R1, I am still getting around 17ohm. Why 17ohm, not close to 1.5ohm?? Thats the part I don't understand. I will decrease the Rref down to 5ohm, and see if that gives me close to 1.5ohm ESR.

Comment: You need to validate your assumptions because they are incorrect.  What is the GBW of Op Amp and if open loop Ro is say 200 ohms so what is closed loop Ro at 175 kHz  .  >1 Ohm? > 1mohm? < 1mOhm?  Choose Rload to get 50% attenuation at resonance (Zmin) with a small signal. (mV)

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 After reading the TSH82 datasheet, the GBW is 65MHz, and the closed loop (voltage follower) Rload is 150ohm till 1MHz (Gain of 10, Vcc = +/-5V). As you said, I will decrease the voltage down to mV, and chose a Rload to get close to 50% attenuation at resonance.

Answer (score 0):

Your maths are correct and your calculated values for ESR are fairly consistent for the various test conditions.

According to [Kemet's K-Sim](https://ksim3.kemet.com/capacitor-simulation), you should expect a capacitor ESR of about 1.8 ohms at 180 kHz for a 1nF, 1210 sized COG capacitor.

The **DC Resistance** of the inductor is 1.5 ohms. This is **not** the same as ESR, but, is a part of the inductor's ESR. An inductor has eddy current losses primarily due to proximity effect and a small amount loss due to skin effect which show up as a real loss. There is also loss in the ferrite, but is probably fairly small for the flux density of your circuit. The DC_resistance + eddy + ferrite losses are known as AC losses that you are measuring.

My guess: you are mainly seeing the AC loss resistance of the inductor plus about 1.8 ohms for the capacitor.

[Edit]
Just for fun, I measured the AC loss resistance of an inductor found in my junk-box on a HP4194A impedance analyzer. You can see the loss resistance of this 10uH inductor increase with frequency. The DC resistance of the inductor is 0.060 ohms, analyzer probes shorted is 0.035 ohms which matches the low frequency loss resistance shown in the graph.

[image]